# Selected options in multi select based on old() OR existing data

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have two models with a many-to-many relationship: `Project` and `User`.

When creating or editing a `User` the below multi select field partial is included in the view.

It loops through the projects and checks if there is data in old(). If there is data in the old() it compares the project `$id` to the array in old() and adds the selected attribute if it exists.   If there is no data in old it plucks the existing $user's project ids into an array - applying the selected attribute if it exists.

```
<select class="form-control" id="projects" name="projects[]" multiple>
    @foreach($projects as $id => $name)
        <option value="{{ $id }}" 
        @if(old("projects")) 
            @if(in_array($id, old("projects"))) 
                selected="selected" 
            @endif 
        @else
            @if(in_array($id, $user->projects->pluck('id')->toArray())) 
                selected="selected" 
            @endif
        @endif > {{ $name }}</option>
    @endforeach                
</select>
```

So this works - but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.  The nested loops feel messy.

Is there a cleaner and more efficient way to accomplish this using blade?

Comment: You could use Laravel collection's `contains` instead of plain PHP `in_array` like this: `@if( $user->projects->pluck('id')->contains($id) )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of code factoring using one-liners, Laravel collection, and Blade directive `@php` to add an extra separation layer between the logic and the display:

```
<select class="form-control" id="projects" name="projects[]" multiple>
    @foreach($projects as $id => $name)
        @php
            $selected = collect(old('projects'))->contains($id) || $user->projects->pluck('id')->contains($id) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        @endphp
        <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ $selected }}> {{ $name }}</option>
    @endforeach                
</select>
```

Blade directive `@php @endphp` let you work as you were at home. 
Laravel `collect` can also work with `null` values, so if your `old('projects')` is null, the collection will be an empty array and it will not pass the `->contains($id)` statement. This saves you another check.

Hope it inspires you.